# Out of bounds error checking for palindrome

Tags: vb.net

Question:
A palindromic number reads the same both ways, e.g 56765, 1221. write the program code that takes a number from a user and output true if the num is palindromic. you program should make use of a stack.

---

Can you please look at this code and tell me why it is giving this out of bounds error?

```
Module Module1

    Dim pnum As String
    Dim top As Integer
    Dim arraystack(top) As Char
    Sub putinstack(ByVal n As String)
        Dim i, lenght As Integer

        top = 0
        lenght = Len(n)
        For i = 1 To lenght
            top = top + 1
            arraystack(i) = Mid(pnum, i, 1)


        Next

    End Sub


    Function palindromic(p As String) As Boolean

        Dim yon As Boolean
        yon = True
        Dim cnt As Integer
        cnt = 0
        While top >= cnt

            cnt = cnt + 1
            While arraystack(top) <> arraystack(cnt)
                yon = False
            End While
            top = top - 1


        End While
        Return yon

    End Function




    Sub Main()

        Console.WriteLine("insert number you wish to know is palindromic or not!")
        pnum = Console.ReadLine.ToString

        Call putinstack(pnum)

        If palindromic(pnum) = True Then

            Console.WriteLine("num is palindromic")
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("num is not palindromic")

        End If

        Console.ReadKey()



    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Which line does the error happen on?

Comment: @AndrewMorton 10th line which is arraystack(i) = mid(pnum,i,1)

Comment: @AndrewMorton it shows error on line 3rd( dim arraystack(top)) as char and 10th says array is out of bounds of the index, sorry im only a beginner :)))

Comment: The line `Dim arraystack(top) As Char` uses the value of `top` at the time that line is run. The value of `top` at that time is 0, so the array only has one element, with an index of 0. You could put `Redim arraystack(lenght)` after the line `lenght = Len(n)`. (P.S. it is spelt `length`.)

Comment: note: without the stack you can solve this with a single line: `Dim IsPalindromic As Boolean = Strings.StrReverse("1221") = "1221"`

Comment: Oh i see, but i did this because it was a question in a levels exam :)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to detect if a string is palindromic this method might be an alternative:

```
Function IsPalindromic(S As String) As Boolean

    If S IsNot Nothing AndAlso S.Length > 0 AndAlso IsNumeric(S) Then
        Dim diff As Integer = S.Length Mod 2
        Dim center As Integer = ((S.Length - diff) / 2)

        Dim sxPart As String = S.Remove(center)
        Dim dxPart As String = S.Remove(0, center + diff)

        dxPart = New String(dxPart.ToArray.Reverse.ToArray)

        Return sxPart = dxPart

    End If
    Return False
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The line `Dim arraystack(top) As Char` uses the value of `top` at the time that line is run. The value of `top` at that time is 0, so the array only has one element, with an index of 0.

You could put `Redim arraystack(lenght)` after the line `lenght = Len(n)`. (P.S. it is spelt `length`.)

Something I noticed is that you have

```
While arraystack(top) <> arraystack(cnt)
    yon = False
End While
```

which would normally be done with an `If...Then` statement, like this:

```
Option Strict On

Module Module1

    Dim pnum As String
    Dim top As Integer
    Dim arraystack() As Char

    Sub PutInStack(ByVal n As String)
        Dim i, length As Integer

        top = 0
        length = Len(n)
        ReDim arraystack(length)

        For i = 1 To length
            top = top + 1
            arraystack(i) = CChar(Mid(pnum, i, 1))
        Next

    End Sub

    Function palindromic(p As String) As Boolean

        Dim yon As Boolean
        yon = True
        Dim cnt As Integer
        cnt = 0
        While top >= cnt
            cnt = cnt + 1
            If arraystack(top) <> arraystack(cnt) Then
                yon = False
            End If

            top = top - 1

        End While

        Return yon

    End Function

    Sub Main()

        Console.WriteLine("Enter number you wish to know is palindromic or not!")
        pnum = Console.ReadLine()

        PutInStack(pnum)

        If palindromic(pnum) = True Then
            Console.WriteLine("num is palindromic")
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("num is not palindromic")
        End If

        Console.ReadKey()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Please notice that I put `Option Strict On` as the first line. That tells Visual Studio to let you know about things that are wrong, such as trying to assign the wrong sort of data into a variable, e.g. you can't use a string as a number, and you can't put a string into a Char, which is why there is a `CChar` in there.